# Push Notifications Android, encoding and decoding

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, push-notification

When I receive notifications in my device I can't avoid seeing weird characters, kind of: Ã­©.

GcmListenerService.class

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    String tit = data.getString("title");
    String message = data.getString("body");

    String title = null;
    try {
        title= URLDecoder.decode(tit, "UTF-8"); // tit and title have the same output
        sendNotification(title,message)
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the server side I do the encoding:

```
$payload = array('body' => utf8_encode($texto),
                 'title' => utf8_encode($name),
                 'Room' => utf8_encode($texto));

$data = array(
          'data' => $payload,
          'to' => $tokenDevice);

$headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: How are the strings on server side after encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I do not encode nor decode any text when I'm sending the push and it looks good on the device.

**PHP Code (to send the Push)**

```
    // API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', $APIKEY );
    $registrationIds = $tokens;

    // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
    (
        'message'   => $message,
        'title'     => $title
    );

    $fields = array
    (
        'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
        'data'          => $msg
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_encode($res);

    echo $result;
```

**Android code to retrieve the push and create notification**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),
       remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.white_notification_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have **Uri** Class in Android which helps us to decode the text to accept all formats in android .

```
String  title = Uri.encode(tit, "UTF-8");
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
/**
     * Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets
     * using the UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers
     * ("0-9"), and unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact. Encodes
     * all other characters with the exception of those specified in the
     * allow argument.
     *
     * @param s string to encode
     * @param allow set of additional characters to allow in the encoded form,
     *  null if no characters should be skipped
     * @return an encoded version of s suitable for use as a URI component,
     *  or null if s is null
     */
```

And for decodeing the message to string :

```
  String message = Uri.decode(encodedMessage);
```

I hope it will solve your problem.